# Why does a single quote SVN commit message change the filepath?

Tags: svn, windows-7, cmd

I noted some strange behavior is exhibited when using a single quote for your SVN commit message on Windows 7:

```
C:\data\projects\XXXX_trunk>svn commit -m 'Turn on server filter' --username XXXX --password XXXX
svn: E200009: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200009: 'C:\data\projects\XXXX_trunk\on' is not under version control
```

As you may notice from the above, the commit fails for a rather strange reason. The second word of the commit message is appended to the root SVN directory which in turn is not actually a directory.

Using double quotes does, in fact, solve the issue, but I am beyond curious to find out why this is happening, why the second word of the commit, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DOS, multi-word arguments are enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes. So `on`, `server`, and `filter'` are the three things you're asking SVN to commit, with the commit message `'Turn`.

Comment: Ah that does make a lot of sense when I think about it. Thanks!